# Прогрессбар в виде неполного круга

Tags: java, android, activity

Добрый вечер, пытался найти информацию в гугле, но не смог - как сделать прогрессбар в андроиде в подобном стиле - круг с "вырезом"?

### [image: ProgressBar]

Сам сейчас использую следующие стили:

### Сам прогрессбар

```
<ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/circularProgressBar"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleHorizontal"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:indeterminate="false"
        android:max="100"
        android:progress="50"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:rotation="90"
        android:background="@drawable/timer_progress_bar_background"
        android:progressDrawable="@drawable/timer_progress_bar_background"
        android:layout_above="@+id/container_TimeCounters" />
```

### Фон

```
<item android:id="@android:id/background" >
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="30.0"
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:thickness="2dp">
        <solid
            android:color="#c7c7c7"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
```

### Активная стадия

```
<item android:id="@android:id/progress">
    <shape
        android:innerRadiusRatio="3"
        android:shape="ring"
        android:thicknessRatio="30.0"
        android:useLevel="true"
        android:thickness="2dp">
        <solid
            android:color="#ff0000"
            />
    </shape>
</item>
```

Answer (score 1):

Искусство девелопера в том числе состоит и в том, чтобы не тратить свое драгоценное время на разработку несущественных для основной деятельности задач.

Искренне надеюсь, что вашей задачей не является разработка

> Прогрессбар в виде неполного круга

Посему попробуйте такой вот кОнтрол - [ArcProgressBar](https://github.com/ZeeeeeeNo/ArcProgressBar), разработанный вездесущими китайцами - несмотря на китайские каменты, вполне же понятно как его применять, не правда ли?

P.S. И совершенно неинтересно как это написано - ну по крайней мере мне.